# Can't set windows name

Tags: c++, char, window, cons, lpcwstr

So I tried to put together a window, but when I needed to name the window I told me.
(Error: argument of type “const char*” is incompatible of type “LPCWSTR”)
Programming for the CreateWindow method is underneath. Error should be in line 2.

---

```
hwnd = CreateWindow(
    "Engine_Winter_Name",
    "Winter Engine",
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION,
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2 - WIDTH/2,
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2 - HEIGHT/2,
    WIDTH,
    HEIGHT,
    (HWND)NULL,
    (HMENU)NULL,
    hInstance,
    (LPVOID*)NULL);

if (!hwnd)
    return false;

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

return true;
```

---

All help is more than welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a wide string. Prefix your strings with L.

```
hwnd = CreateWindow(
    L"Engine_Winter_Name",
    L"Winter Engine",
```

Answer (score 0):

You're compiling with `UNICODE` defined, which means that e.g. the `CreateWindow` macro maps to `CreateWindowW`, which expects wide character (`wchar_t`-based) arguments:

```
hwnd = CreateWindow(
    L"Engine_Winter_Name",
    L"Winter Engine",
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION,
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2 - WIDTH/2,
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2 - HEIGHT/2,
    WIDTH,
    HEIGHT,
    HWND(),
    HMENU(),
    hInstance,
    nullptr);

if (!hwnd)
    return false;

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
```

For modern Windows desktop programming it's generally best to use the Unicode based API, as you're doing.